# Show area and dimensions of polygons in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

In the code below, I add the polygon layer to the map according to the coordinates of its vertices. Now, when adding a polygon, I want the area and size of its sides to be added as well.. Like [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html) topic. However, in this topic, the sides and area are calculated when drawing. I already have the coordinates of the vertices and when the polygon layer is added to the map, I want its dimensions to be added as well.

```
const missionCoords = msg.payload[0].missionCoords;
  const polygonCoords = [];
  missionCoords.forEach(element => {
    polygonCoords.push(transform(element, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
  });

  const polygon = new Polygon([polygonCoords]);
  const polygonFeature = new Feature({
    geometry: polygon,
  });
  polygonLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new Vector({
      features: [polygonFeature]
    }),
    style: {
      'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
      'stroke-color': '#000066',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      'circle-radius': 1,
      'circle-fill-color': '#ffcc33',
    }
  });
  map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

Comment: Thank you, I edit it.

Comment: You would need to style the layers with a style function based on the one used in the example.  Use your own style as the base style and, if you are only interested in existing polygon areas, you can remove code which is specific to drawing and linestrings. https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-areas-9594gc?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank you, It's worked